# An error occurring when publishing my WinForm application in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I get the following error -

> An error occurred while signing: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

Is there any solutions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: And what is in the application event log?

Comment: It's telling you what it recommends you do.... `Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.` - Quick search on google yield - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/this-application-failed-to-start-because-side-by/7673bf12-87c2-48ca-b5ae-b8aa85e295dc

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, this error has everything you need in it to solve the problem- it's already recommending you to do something to fix it. The first thing you should be doing is taking that advice and look at the system's event log and/or the sxstrace.exe tool.

You can also do a quick search online; you can literally copy and paste the full error to get the following from Microsoft help forums: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/this-application-failed-to-start-because-side-by/7673bf12-87c2-48ca-b5ae-b8aa85e295dc

1. **Use the System File Checker tool (SFC.exe)** to determine which file is causing the issue, and then replace the file. To do this, follow these steps:
   Open an elevated command prompt. To do this, click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator. If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click Allow.
   Type the following command, and then press ENTER: `sfc /scannow`

The `sfc /scannow` command scans all protected system files and replaces incorrect versions with correct Microsoft versions.

More Information about SFC scan can be found in this document:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

2. **Perform a check disk:** Open Computer by clicking the Start button and then clicking Computer. Right-click the drive that you want to check, and then click Properties. Click the Tools tab, and then, under Error-checking, click Check now.

If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

To automatically repair problems with files and folders that the scan detects, select Automatically fix file system errors. Otherwise, the disk check will report problems but not fix them.

To perform a thorough check, select Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors. This scan attempts to find and repair physical errors on the drive itself, and it can take much longer to complete.

To check for both file errors and physical errors, select both Automatically fix file system errors and Scan for and attempt recovery of bad sectors.
Click Start.

Depending on the size of your drive, this might take several minutes. For best results, don't use your computer for any other tasks while it is checking for errors.

3. **Update the .NET framework**

Download and install the latest .NET Framework
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en

4. **If still, the error persists then provide an error log:** Type `eventvwr.msc /s` in the address bar.

   List any events that are listed as "Error" in the main window when you go to "Windows Logs" and "Application." There are often a lot of them. Send us whichever ones you see listed for the last couple days. (Please also do for the logs in "System"). When you do, provide us the name of the "Source" and whatever is listed in the description box below the list of logs when you click on one.

Comment: Got it Solved by modifying Visual studio and adding Tools(1.4.1) and windows 10 SDK under Windows app Development Tools